# Add ellipsize to first text when it is long in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `Row` with 2 `Text` in it

```
       Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(16.dp),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "text1",
                        maxLines = 1,
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                        modifier = Modifier.wrapContentWidth(),
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(4.dp))

                    Text(
                        text = "(text2)",
                        maxLines = 1,
                        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                    )
                }
```

[image]

if text1 is long, text2 has no place so this happened:
[image]

how can I fix this?
accepted: [image]

Comment: Maybe you need to use `SubcomposeLayout` to do actual size measurement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [RowScope.weight](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/RowScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).weight(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Boolean)) for first text and pass `fill = false` to avoid occupying whole width.

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(16.dp),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
) {
    Text(
        text = "text1",
        maxLines = 1,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, fill = false),
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(4.dp))

    Text(
        text = "(text2)",
        maxLines = 1,
    )
}
```